# how to stop text color function under conio.h in C to align the output to right??is there any way to reset text attributes to normal in C

Tags: c, text-alignment, textcolor, text-coloring, conio

```
int main()
{
    int i ;
    clrscr();
    for(i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            **textcolor(2);**
            cprintf("%d\n", i);
        }

        if(i % 2 != 0) {
            **textcolor(3);**
            cprintf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

OUTPUT:(all evens are in green and odds in blue)

```
0

 1

  2

   3

    4

      5

        6
```

Comment: As a member for over one month you should have had time to read lots of questions, and see how they are formatted. In the future please refrain from putting the question in the title only and just have some code and/or output in the body of the question without any description of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `\n` is used literally and only does a line feed (= jump to next line and keep cursor at same column) and no carriage return (= put cursor at start of line). Change the `\n`s inside the calls to `cprintf` to `\r\n`.

Comment: @user1642219 Just as a hint: The biggest thank you is accepting answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Newlines in Windows is `"\r\n"`. Apparently the `cprintf` doesn't translate `'\n'` into the correct sequence so all you are doing is going to the next line with the line feed but you do not put the "cursor" at the beginning if the line with `'\r'` (carriage return).